# Uncaught TypeError : Cannot read property 'websiteId' of undefined

Tags: javascript, frontend-error, pdp

This error occurs when entering the product as pdp.
I'm getting an error that I'm using the websiteId somewhere and I can't get it, but I'm not sure what exactly is causing it.

Do you have any solution?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `window.checkout` obj does not have `websiteId` in it.
In browser console enter `window.checkout` & see the data it has.
make changes according to it.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.
As a result of the check, the E-commerce function was not turned on, so the websiteId value could not be retrieved.

Comment: How to turn it on?